# Swagger UI showing "Fetch error Not Found"

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-2.1

in my asp.net core 2.1 api I have added static files serving and Swashbuckle, but apparently can't find the generated .json

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(x =>
    x.SwaggerDoc("Swagger", new Info { Title = "Asp.Net Core 2 Api", Description = "Swagger Core Api" }));
----
app.UseCors("AllowAll");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(x => x.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/swagger.json", "Core Api"));
```

[image]

any idea? thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your swagger end-point has the wrong Url, hence the 'Not Found' Error.
Swagger documents constructed via the default way have their url in the format `/swagger/<document-name>/swagger.json` where  is the **name** *(first string)* parameter supplied in the call to `x.SwaggerDoc("Swagger", new Info {...});`

In your case you supplied "Swagger", hence your endpoint url should be `"/swagger/Swagger/swagger.json"`.

and in your ConfigureServices your call should be like

`app.UseSwaggerUI(x => x.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/Swagger/swagger.json", "Core Api"));`

Comment: I found it and forgot to update my question, but yes that's the correct answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

After publishing the application on IIS,
I had this same problem, here is how I solved it.

In the `Startup.cs` file Add in the `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)...` method

```
services.AddSwaggerGen();
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("OpenAPISpec",
        new OpenApiInfo()
        {
            Title = "Your Title here",
            Version = "1",
            Description = "A simple example ASP.NET Core Web API",
            TermsOfService = new Uri("https://example.com/terms"),
            Contact = new OpenApiContact()
            {
                Email = "youremail@gmail.com",
                Name = "Jean Fritz DUVERSEAU",
                Url = new Uri("https://www.rezo509.com")
            }
        });

    var xmlCommentFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    var xmlCommentsFullPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlCommentFile);
    options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlCommentsFullPath);
});
```

and then in the `public void Configure(...` method

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(s =>
{
    string swaggerPath = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.RoutePrefix) ? "." : "..";
    s.SwaggerEndpoint($"{swaggerPath}/swagger/OpenAPISpec/swagger.json", "Demo API");
});
```

After that execute the project, then in the browser modify the url as follows:

http (s): //yourserver.com:[port]`/swagger/index.html`
[image]

if you dont add the correct url you will have `HTTP ERROR 404`
[image]

And after publication on the IIS server
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: you must check the path prefix difference on your environments and reflect this difference in SwaggerEndpoint([different path]) option.
One of convenient ways is to automate this difference is to put this selection to `#if DEBUG` section

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me
`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
        {
            Title = "Test API",
            Version = "v1",
            Description = "List of Api's.",
            Contact = new OpenApiContact
            {
                Name = "Test site",
                Email = string.Empty
            },
        });
    });
    services.AddCors();
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddSingleton<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddControllers();
}
```

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
app.UseSwagger();

```
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "  API V1");
        c.RoutePrefix = "swagger";
    });


    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

`

---

Try copy pasting your application link om a browser
e.g.  http://localhost/testsite/swagger/v1/swagger.json
compare it with the link in the error.
Tweak the url in c.SwaggerEndpoint accordingly